# How to write a_b,not a_{b}

Tags: math-mode

how can I get like this [image] ?thanks.

Comment: You are doing something very odd if you manage to convert a to g, so better show a small but complete example.

Comment: thanks, I have changed my odd expression.

Comment: Erh, no you haven't, the image have nothing to do with the question you ask. However the image ought to be `$J_{g\_z}`

Comment: `$J_{a\textunderscore b}$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably post a MWE to fully explain what you want..
I assume you want something like `$J_{a\_b}$` and are using some encoding like `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, so you don't like how the underscore between a and b looks like.

Try using the command `\rule[h]{w}{t}` to draw a horizontal line (control the `w` argument for the width you want and the other two for vertical positioning and thickness, all are tex length):

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

$J_{a\_b}$ %underscore is too long?

$J_{a\rule[-.1em]{1ex}{.4pt}b}$

\end{document}
```

You may want to try `\usepackage{fontenc}` or `\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}`, if they don't break anything else in your document, they at least render a shorter underscore in the MWE.

Comment: thanks! the second way is what I want!

Comment: Then please mark it as accepted answer